# django orm multiple filter on same many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Suppose I want to get books having atleast two author's whose first names are Test and Tester.So I will proceed with `Book.objects.filter(authors__first_name='Test').filter(authors__first_name='Tester')`

What if I have multiple first name(long list) to check,apart from running a for loop and rawsqlquery are there other options?

```
queryset = Book,objects.all()
for i in ['test','tester']:
   queryset = queryset.filter(authors__first_name=i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter with:

```
datas = ['test', tester']
qs = Book.objects.all()
for datum in datas:
    qs = qs.filter(authors__first_name=datum)
```

But this will not scale well, and furthermore you will retrieve the same book.

What works better is to `Count` the number of `Author`s with `test` or `tester` as first name:

```
datas = set(['test', 'tester'])

Book.objects.filter(
    authors__first_name__in=datas
).annotate(
    nauthors=Count('authors')
).filter(nauthors=len(data))
```

or since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can make use of the [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent counting twice (once for the filter, and once for the `SELECT` clause):

```
datas = set(['test', 'tester'])

Book.objects.filter(
    authors__first_name__in=datas
).alias(
    nauthors=Count('authors')
).filter(nauthors=len(data))
```

Here we thus will make *one* JOIN with the table of the `Author` model, and simply count the number of authors that match.

Comment: what if I have a list of dict to compare  like   [{ 'first_name': 'test', 'last_name': 'user' }, {'first_name': 'Tester', 'last_name': 'user2'}]  containing both authors with their respective first and last name.

Comment: @Madmax: can you please ask a new question. It makes it clear for future readers what problem is solved.

Comment: :Here the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68258360/django-orm-multiple-filter-on-same-many-to-many-fields)