# django orm multiple filter on same many to many fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I want to find Books containing both the authors with first_name and last_name in the below list without using for loop(mentioned below) or raw query.

```
authors = [{
'first_name' : 'Test',
'last_name' : 'user1',
},
{'first_name' : 'Tester',
 'last_name': 'user2'
}
]

queryset = Book,objects.all()
for i in authors:
   queryset = queryset.filter(authors__first_name=i.get('first_name',None), authors__last_name=i.get('last_name',None))
```

Comment: What's the problem with the loop? It does what you want and is perhaps the only solution in your case (Chained calls to `.filter()` are needed to make multiple joins here), if you believe the loop is slowing you down you are wrong it's query you want itself that is slowing you down (since it will cause multiple joins).

Answer (score 1):

What I would propose is to use `Q()` in order it looks better:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()
for i in authors:
    query |= Q(
        authors__first_name=i['first_name'], 
        authors__last_name=i['last_name']
    )

queryset = Book.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Does it maybe need a `distinct()` on the end there to remove duplicates in case the list of authors co-authored the same book?

Comment: @getup8 It needs a count aggregation compared with `len(authors)` to remove the ones that match only one of the authors (this would also remove the duplicates due to aggregating).

Comment: Ah yeah I think I misinterpreted the question. They’re trying to find books with *both* authors?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, this might look like:

```sql
-- Note the DISTINCT since there could be multiple authors to
-- the same book and you probably only want to return it once.
SELECT DISTINCT
  b.id,
  b.title  
FROM
  book AS b
  JOIN book_author AS ba
    ON b.id = ba.book_id
  JOIN author AS a
    ON ba.author_id = a.id
WHERE
  -- You need a new line here for every pair of conditions...
  (a.first_name = 'Test' AND a.last_name = 'user1')
  OR (a.first_name = 'Tester' AND a.last_name = 'user2xx')
```

I could be wrong but I don't think you'll get around using a `for` loop for this.

(An answer came in using `Q()` above which looks good; will post this anyway in case the SQL is helpful for others)